# Convert all pandas dataframe columns to string, datetime or numeric depending on content

Tags: python, pandas, types

I often make API requests that send back json. I store this in a pandas dataframe, and columns will be a mix of dates, strings and numerics (across columns) and unfortunately a mix of float and int inside the same column for numerics. For example, a json value like 50 will become int, 50.03 float, so pandas column type will be object.

When storing the dataframe as hdf, I get the complaint that pickling will be required, so wanted to cast all columns as their correct type first to avoid it.

My question is how to do that cleanly for the entire dataframe?

I tried df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore"), which works for numerics, but then would have to do the same for strings and dates, and chaining these would format my numerics as dates. Is there a better way?